# .Net Debugging loading of assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, mef

I have an application whose forms open up slowly the first time, after that the form is very quick to open. I have gone through and removed unwanted references using JustCode. So the application should be down to just the assemblies needed. This reduced the load time. Then I added some debugging code to show the assemblies being loaded after the form is created.

```
        var currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        currentDomain.AssemblyLoad += AssemblyLoadHandler;
        currentDomain.AssemblyResolve += AssemblyResolveHandler;
```

The method AssemblyLoadHandler just writes the assembly being loaded to a log file. The log file shows some of our third party assemblies as being loaded. I know these assemblies are not used so I deleted them from the directory. Once they are removed they do NOT appear as being loaded. I have checked the assembly references using JustDecompile and running Process Explorer and looking at loaded dlls in .Net Assemblies tab. These third party dlls do not show up in the list of loaded assemblies.

Is the method I am using to track this down sound or is there something I am doing wrong, and is the reporting of a dll, being loaded, by the callback AssemblyLoad accurate?

Update:

I am also using the resolve handler callback but only one dll is reported through that route and it is one that is needed. I tried debugging using the RequestingAssembly.FullName but none of the other dlls are reported through the resolve handler:

```
        currentDomain.AssemblyResolve += AssemblyResolveHandler;
```

Update 1:

I forgot an important consideration I am using MEF in this application and it is .Net 4.5.1. In the code there is the loading of assembly catalogs, but I have not seen any method yet to find out if other dlls are being loaded. The dlls that are loaded by assembly catalog are required and there is no dynamic loading of assemblies using Assembly.Load.

Update 2:
I will try taking a snap shot of the dlls loaded in the AppDomain base on this articles approach
[When is an assembly loaded](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Nov/03/Back-to-Basics-When-does-a-NET-Assembly-Dependency-get-loaded)

Update 3:

A call to AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() gets a list of assemblies loaded before the create and initialize of the form. After the creation of the form get the list of loaded assemblies again. Then do a difference on the before and after lists to show the assemblies that were loaded. The difference list for me were things I expected, but the list reported by AssemblyLoad contains dlls that are not used and are not in the dependencies for the application or its reference assemblies. 
I think the usage of the [AssemblyLoad](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyload%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) callback is clear cut and the descriptions says it occurs when an assembly is loaded. But the information it reported to me seems incorrect.

Any information you can provide is appreciated.

Comment: I am surprised you did not get errors when you removed the files. .NET loads assemblies as stuff requests things from them for the first time, so if your assemblies where loaded it is because something used that assembly.

Comment: Unless, perhaps, there's some dynamic discovery of non-essential (plug-in?) assemblies going on.

Comment: I guess I'm confused on why you're using your approach.  Since it looks like you have access to the source, why not open your solution in VS, open the references folder and look for all the non-standard assemblies in the source of the app?  From there you can gauge performance & refactor as needed / possible depending on which dll is called by which part fo the code.

Comment: I have the source code. so I have access to the references folder. I have scoured all the references using JustCode and by hand. As I said Process Explorer reports what I expect for assemblies that are being loaded, but Assembly.Load reports others that are not used. That is why I tried the delete of the dlls and then Assembly.Load does not report them.

Comment: I am going to also try taking a before and after snap shot of dlls using the information from this article. This might check validity of AssemblyLoad callback:

Comment: http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Nov/03/Back-to-Basics-When-does-a-NET-Assembly-Dependency-get-loaded